# NetworkX matcher for subgraph isomorphism

Tags: python, match, networkx, subgraph, isomorphism

is there a way to find mapping of nodes when searching subgraph isomorphism via NetworkX? For example,

```
import numpy as np
from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
import networkx as nx

B = [[0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
     [2, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

A = [[0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 2],
     [1, 2, 0]]

G1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(B), create_using=nx.MultiGraph())
G2 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(A), create_using=nx.MultiGraph())
GM = isomorphism.MultiGraphMatcher(G1,G2)
print(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic())
print(GM.mapping)
```

Prints `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}`, but it is not true.

Comment: For me this prints `{}` .  What version of nx are you using?  To check use `nx.__version__`

Comment: @Joel the version is 2.0

Comment: Same for me.  Have you really run exactly this block of code?

Comment: @Joel I found that when there is `print(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic())` before printing mapping, the results are different..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
GM = isomorphism.MultiGraphMatcher(G1, G2, edge_match=lambda x, y: x[0]['weight'] == y[0]['weight'])
```

According to source code documentation, there should be edge_match function specified for multigraphs.